# Star Micronics SM-T300i printer need help to print Bitmap in Android Studio

Tags: android, bitmap, stario-sdk

I needed to print from an android device to a Star Micronics SM-T300i printer a simple barcode but it's outputting something like android.graphics.Bitmap@90d50a0 or random numbers. I keep going back to the APK and the SDK but seems to be struggling finding codes that is similar to the previous developer of the mobile application.

**This code is responsible for adding text that can be printed in text.**

```
ArrayList<PrintObject> printObjectList = new ArrayList<PrintObject>();
printObjectList.add(super.createPrintObject((byte) 1, (byte) 1, "Hello World", padding.noPadding));
```

```
    public PrintObject createPrintObject(byte height, byte width,
                                         String strValue, padding padDirection) {
        PrintObject prtObj = new PrintObject();
        ArrayList<Byte> command = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        BluetoothPrintCommand.AddRange(command, BluetoothPrintCommand
                .setcharacterSize((byte) height, (byte) width));
        BluetoothPrintCommand.AddRange(command,
                BluetoothPrintCommand.boldText(false));
        prtObj.setCommands(command);
        String formattedStr = "";
        int padLen = 0;
        if (strValue != null) {
            if (width == 0) {
                padLen = ((WIDTH_ZERO_MAX_CHARACTERS - strValue.length()) / 2)
                        + strValue.length();
                formattedStr = padString(strValue, padLen, padDirection);
            } else if (width == 1) {
                padLen = ((WIDTH_ONE_MAX_CHARACTERS - strValue.length()) / 2)
                        + strValue.length();
                formattedStr = padString(strValue, padLen - 1, padDirection);
            }
        }
        prtObj.setPrintValue(formattedStr);
        return prtObj;
    }
```

**I tried doing this but return prtObj as a Bitmap and it's still being printed in text.**

I can't find solution anywhere with this code, the printing is capable of printing a barcode but I can't find anyone that can help me with corporating it with the same codes present.

```
MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode("Text to convert to Barcode", BarcodeFormat.CODABAR, 10, 5);
            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitMap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            //byteArray = convertBitmapToByteArray(bitMap);
        }catch (WriterException e) {
            Log.e("StarPrinterManager", "Error printing image: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

This is my process of converting text into barcode. I think I'm doing something wrong here. I don't know whether I should pass the data as byte[], Bitmap, or bytes.